Replace wrong driver in USB HUB
I recently added a WiFi/BT card to my PC, the software install seemed to run normally - but I noticed later that an old Belkin USB hub had somehow acquired a messed-up set of properties, it's got a mix of BT and USB now.
E.g. Service Name is "BTHUSB" & service description is "@bth.inf,%BTHUSB.SvcDesc%;Bluetooth Radio USB Driver". The driver InfPath is now "oem76.inf", the driver I downloaded from Belkin for this model is "ax88772.inf_amd64_eb961649dbff943e"
Now I can't restart the PC without disconnecting this hub first.
It's defying all the things that normally would reset the hub, included driver/device uninstalls,
deleting properties with regedit. I can display ALL the hub's incorrect properties using USBDeview - so how can I edit the properties - unless someone has a better way of fixing this?
